# Accessing Hive Table Data with MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hcatalog

In single node installation of Hadoop 2.2, I am trying to run Cloudera example "Accessing Table Data with MapReduce" that copies data from one table to another:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_19_6.html

Example code compiles with numerous deprecation warnings (see below). 
Before running this example from Eclipse, I create input table 'simple' in Hive default DB. I pass input 'simple' and output 'simpid' tables on a command line. Notwithstanding input table already exists in default DB, when I run this code I get exception:

```
 java.io.IOException: NoSuchObjectException(message:default.simple table not found
```

Questions:

1) Why does "table not found" exception happen? How to solve this?

2) How does deprecated HCatRecord, HCatSchema, HCatBaseInputFormat in this example translate to a latest, stable API?

```
package com.bigdata;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.data.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.data.schema.*;

public class UseHCat extends Configured implements Tool {

 public static class Map extends Mapper<WritableComparable, HCatRecord, Text, IntWritable> {
  String groupname;

    @Override
  protected void map( WritableComparable key,
                      HCatRecord value,
                      org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<WritableComparable, HCatRecord,
                      Text, IntWritable>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // The group table from /etc/group has name, 'x', id
        groupname = (String) value.get(0);
        int id = (Integer) value.get(1);
        // Just select and emit the name and ID
        context.write(new Text(groupname), new IntWritable(id));
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable,
                                   WritableComparable, HCatRecord> {

    protected void reduce( Text key,
                           java.lang.Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                           org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, IntWritable,
                           WritableComparable, HCatRecord>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Only expecting one ID per group name
        Iterator<IntWritable> iter = values.iterator();
        IntWritable iw = iter.next();
        int id = iw.get();
        // Emit the group name and ID as a record
        HCatRecord record = new DefaultHCatRecord(2);
        record.set(0, key.toString());
        record.set(1, id);
        context.write(null, record);
    }
}

public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    args = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

    // Get the input and output table names as arguments
    String inputTableName = args[0];
    String outputTableName = args[1];
    // Assume the default database
    String dbName = null;

    Job job = new Job(conf, "UseHCat");
    HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, InputJobInfo.create(dbName,
            inputTableName, null));
    job.setJarByClass(UseHCat.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    // An HCatalog record as input
    job.setInputFormatClass(HCatInputFormat.class);

    // Mapper emits a string as key and an integer as value
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // Ignore the key for the reducer output; emitting an HCatalog record as value
    job.setOutputKeyClass(WritableComparable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(DefaultHCatRecord.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(HCatOutputFormat.class);

    HCatOutputFormat.setOutput(job, OutputJobInfo.create(dbName,
               outputTableName, null));
    HCatSchema s = HCatOutputFormat.getTableSchema(job);
    System.err.println("INFO: output schema explicitly set for writing:" + s);
    HCatOutputFormat.setSchema(job, s);
    return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new UseHCat(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
 }
}
```

When I run this on a single-node Hadoop 2.2 I get the following exception:

```
14/03/05 15:17:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/03/05 15:17:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir.recursive is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive
14/03/05 15:17:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.max.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize
14/03/05 15:17:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.min.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize
14/03/05 15:17:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.min.split.size.per.rack is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.rack
14/03/05 15:17:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.min.split.size.per.node is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.node
14/03/05 15:17:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
14/03/05 15:17:21 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
14/03/05 15:17:22 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
14/03/05 15:17:22 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
14/03/05 15:17:23 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
14/03/05 15:17:24 WARN bonecp.BoneCPConfig: Max Connections < 1. Setting to 20
14/03/05 15:17:25 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
14/03/05 15:17:25 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
14/03/05 15:17:27 WARN bonecp.BoneCPConfig: Max Connections < 1. Setting to 20
14/03/05 15:17:27 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_database: NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck
14/03/05 15:17:27 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=dk  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck 
14/03/05 15:17:27 ERROR metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: NoSuchObjectException(message:There is no database named nonexistentdatabaseusedforhealthcheck)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getMDatabase(ObjectStore.java:431)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDatabase(ObjectStore.java:441)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.invoke(RetryingRawStore.java:124)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_database(HiveMetaStore.java:628)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:103)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.get_database(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getDatabase(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:810)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.isOpen(HiveClientCache.java:277)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:147)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveClient(HCatUtil.java:547)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.getInputJobInfo(InitializeInput.java:104)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.setInput(InitializeInput.java:86)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:87)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:56)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:48)
at com.bigdata.UseHCat.run(UseHCat.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at com.bigdata.UseHCat.main(UseHCat.java:91)

14/03/05 15:17:27 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=simple
14/03/05 15:17:27 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=dk  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=simple   
14/03/05 15:17:27 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
14/03/05 15:17:27 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.

     Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: NoSuchObjectException(message:default.simple table not found)

at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:89)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:56)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:48)
at com.bigdata.UseHCat.run(UseHCat.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at com.bigdata.UseHCat.main(UseHCat.java:91)
    Caused by: NoSuchObjectException(message:default.simple table not found)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_table(HiveMetaStore.java:1373)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:103)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.get_table(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:854)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getTable(HCatUtil.java:193)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.getInputJobInfo(InitializeInput.java:105)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.setInput(InitializeInput.java:86)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:87)
... 6 more
14/03/05 15:17:29 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 1: Shutting down the object store...
14/03/05 15:17:29 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=dk  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=Shutting down the object store...   
14/03/05 15:17:29 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 1: Metastore shutdown complete.
14/03/05 15:17:29 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=dk  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=Metastore shutdown complete.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't have `hive-site.xml` in your eclipse classpath.  Hive looks for the metastore server address in your configuration.  When it can't find the address, it creates or loads an embedded metastore.  This metastore, of course, does not have the table you created.

**Edit (In answer to your comment):**

Yes you can get values by key, but in order to do that you need the `HCatSchema` for the table. Do this in the map setup phase...

```
HCatSchema schema = HCatBaseInputFormat.getTableSchema(context.getConfiguration);
```

And in the map phase...

```
value.get('field', schema);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to access table metadata such as field names and their types from 'Mapper.map' method? So instead of getting HCatRecord field values by index like 'value.get(0)' use 'value' as an associative array to get values by key like 'value.getKey("aFieledName") ?

Comment: Putting `hive-site.xml` in CLASSPATH helped. Next problem was that I could not create output table from my code and had to do this manually from Hive shell run as `hive` user. Now when run under regular user my code has no `write` permission and I get: `org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=dk, access=WRITE, inode="/apps/hive/warehouse/simpids":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x` Please advise how to set permissionn so regular user could create tables and write data in Hive. Many thanks!

Comment: You probably have to set the permissions of the warehouse directory.  `hadoop fs -chmod ....`.  Don't know the exact syntax, but you can look it up.